# How to invoke a stored procedure from DbUpdate Activity from the Workflow Designer

Tags: oracle11g, workflow, relational-database, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-rehosting

I open my rehosted workflow Designer, then I open my workflow which includes a DpUpdate Activity (for information on DbUpdate Activity you can use the following link )

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622977.aspx).  In the strSQL argument of the DbUpdate Activity I know how to put insert, update etc.. commands.  However, I don't know how to invoke a stored procedure.

when I type

execute USER_NAM.Stored_ProcedureName (param1, param2)
 Workflow e146c071-c363-4728-a565-36175394bedc Terminated.
 Exception: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 16:
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ; immediate
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 65:
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
..
..
..

Do you have any suggestions on how to invoke a stored procedure from within DbUpdate Activity? 
Thanks

Comment: The link you gave are just samples. You've to come up with your own DbExecute activity. If you already have the samples it should be easy.

Comment: Thank you for your  help. I found my answer and listed it below, I did not find it in the documentation, just stepping through the Workflow Designer led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer.  In DbUpdate activity's list of argument there is a CommandType.  As long as you set the CommandType to StoredProcedure (available from the drop down menu), then you simply have to populate the other listed argument(Sql) to the following:

USER_NAM.Stored_ProcedureName (param1, param2)

No need to use "execute" in the Sql string.